# Angular 13 - Initialize FormControl from Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an angular application with one component that has a Reactive Form with a single FormControl, this FormControl lives inside a ngComponent in which is injected a ngService which has an Observable that represents the value.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-preferences',
  templateUrl: './preferences.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./preferences.component.css']
})
export class PreferencesComponent implements OnInit {
  url = new FormControl();
  //...
}

// -----

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PreferencesService {

  private readonly url= new BehaviorSubject<string>("http://localhost:5433");
  readonly url$ = this.url.asObservable();

  updateUrl(url: string) {
    this.url.next(url);
  }
```

How do you initialize the default value for the FormControl from the Service Observable?
What is the best way to connect normal rxjs Observable and FormControl?

I tried this code:

```
constructor(
    private readonly pref: PreferencesService
) { 
    this.pref.url$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(x => this.url.patchValue(x));
    this.url.valueChanges.subscribe(x => this.pref.updateUrl(x));
}
```

And it works but I think it is an awful solution.

Comment: why do you need the url value to be wrapped in a subject and living in a service? Also, what does `this.pref.url(x)` do? what is `url` in the service? it can't be the private readonly url...

Comment: sorry it's the call `updateUrl(x)`, fixed the typo. The url in the service it's just a string, I need the url in the service cause it's share between other parts of the app that has to react to the change of the url.